# getting XML from web behind authentication

Tags: java, android, xml, http, parsing

me again, sorry :)

I was using dom parser to get xml from web and parse it and put the data in db.. all was fine and dandy but than I put basic authentication for folder where the xml is on web...

before it worked like this:

```
final String URL = getString(R.string.url);

// XML node keys
final String KEY_ITEM = "plan"; // parent node
final String KEY_NAME = "agent";
final String KEY_DATE = "date";
final String KEY_SHIFT = "shift";
final String KEY_LINE = "line";

XMLhandler parser = new XMLhandler();
String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML
Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);

// empty table
db.dropData("plan");


for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
String name = parser.getValue(e, KEY_NAME);
String date = parser.getValue(e, KEY_DATE);
String shift = parser.getValue(e, KEY_SHIFT);
String line = parser.getValue(e, KEY_LINE);
db.createList(name, date, shift, line); // add to db

}
```

How do I implement authentication to this ? I know I should use something like:

```
Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {
 @Override
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
         return new PasswordAuthentication(
   "user", "password".toCharArray());
        }
});
```

from what I was looking over this forum, and google... but so far no luck, I do not understand java so good ( still learning ) how do I do it ? I mean how do I get the xml after authentication to parser, I ended up with stream and parser wants string...

I know I might not be making much sense :)

Vlad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have done it ! took about 4 hours to learn it and figure it out.. and lots and lots of googling :D

but here is how I did it, maybe somebody can use it also:

```
URI lUri = new URI(getString(R.string.url)); //get url from strings

// XML node keys
final String KEY_ITEM = "plan"; // parent node
final String KEY_NAME = "agent";
final String KEY_DATE = "date";
final String KEY_SHIFT = "shift";
final String KEY_LINE = "line";

XMLhandler parser = new XMLhandler();

// Prepares the request
HttpClient lHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet lHttpGet = new HttpGet();
lHttpGet.setURI(lUri);
lHttpGet.addHeader(BasicScheme.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordCredentials("user", "pass"), "UTF-8", false));

// Sends the request and read the response
HttpResponse lHttpResponse = lHttpClient.execute(lHttpGet);
InputStream lInputStream = lHttpResponse.getEntity().getContent();

DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document dom = builder.parse(lInputStream);

Element root = dom.getDocumentElement();
NodeList nl = root.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);

// pass data to another function...
for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
   Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
   String name = parser.getValue(e, KEY_NAME);
   String date = parser.getValue(e, KEY_DATE);
   String shift = parser.getValue(e, KEY_SHIFT);
   String line = parser.getValue(e, KEY_LINE);
   db.createList(name, date, shift, line);
}
```

Working so far, its not the best solution I guess but hey! its working :)