# HttpClient authentication in Android

Tags: java, android, apache, authentication

I am trying to get XML from web under authentication using Android. The url look like this : https://host01:443/xxx/items.

However, I get few errors and show that there is  no response from the server side as I cannot access the authenticated url.
Error: java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host : No address associated with hostname.

So, I have tried 3 methods but didnt work.
First one via java.net Authenticator.
Second one via Apache Credentials.
Third one ... I dont know, I just got it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9037734/getting-xml-from-web-behind-authentication).

I know second is better than first one as I am using HttpClient to connect. Or maybe someone can explain to me which is better in use.

Here the code:

```
public class ParseXML {

public String XMLUrlHttpRequest(String Url, final String userName, final String password) {
    String xml_string = null;
    String host = "host01";
    String domain ="abc-123";

    try {

        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        // --1--Authentication using Java.net
        Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator(){
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(userName,password.toCharArray());
            }});
        //--2--Authentication using Apache Credentials
        httpClient.getParams().setParameter(ConnRoutePNames.DEFAULT_PROXY,new HttpHost(host,443));
        Credentials creds = new NTCredentials(userName, password,host,domain);
        httpClient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY,creds);

        //Http Request
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(Url);
        //--3-- Authentication after access to Url 
        httpGet.addHeader(BasicScheme.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordCredentials(userName, password), "UTF-8", false));

        //Http Response
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);    //<---- error here "java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host :  No address associated with hostname"
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        xml_string = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
      ...

    return xml_string;
}
```

}

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it is not a good answer but it works for me. Share for the people who struggling in same situation.

Use Wi-fi rather than connect to the computer network via usb although they use the same network. It sounds stupid but I have no idea with that.

Answer (score 0):

Your URL seams wrong. You can test if it really works from your Android browser.
If it works, you can try to use [HttpsURLConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/net/ssl/HttpsURLConnection.html) instead of HttpClient.

Comment: The Url is right, but I need to run as the specific user to get into, with a domain. Thank you for response.